# Best practice where put method that depends on 2 different object's

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 classes each has his own method's.

I need to make a calculation where I need the value of those 2 methods.

In some other classes I need the value of this calculation.

Where do I put this method that needs the input of 2 different objects and is needed in several other classes?

A simplified example:

```
public class One
 {
   public double item1 {get;set;}
   public double item2 {get;set;}

  public double MethodClassOne()
   {
     return
           item1 * item2;

    }
  }

public class Two
 {
   public double item1 {get;set;}
   public double item2 {get;set;}

  public double MethodClassTwo()
   {
     return
           item1 * item2;

    }
  }

public class C
 {
   public double item1 {get;set;}
   public double item2 {get;set;}
   public double item3 {get; private set;}

  public C(One one, Two two)
  {

    this.item3 =  MethodClassOneAndTwo(one, two);

  }
  public double MethodClassC()
   {
     return
           item1 + item2 + item3;

    }
  }
```

> ```
>   Where do I put this method???
>   MethodClassOneAndTwo(One one, Two two)
>    {
>         One.MethodOne() + two.MethodTwo();
>
>    }
> ```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve btw? In simple terms, even if it's just for learning.

Comment: I make an app. to compute industrial transformers. there is a core and a spoil.
By making calculations with properties of the core and the spoil I can find a surface-temperature, this temperature is somthing i need in several other calculations.

Comment: Okay good to know. You could have this all in one class, but I seem to have misplaced my "Industrial  Transformers for Dummies" handbook, so you'll have to edit your question to rename the classes and methods so it's easy for me to know how you want to operate on each part of the data.

Comment: Sorry for the bad example but I can't use the RL code because it is to complicated and written in dutch.
the only thing I want to know is where can i best put the method that needs value of 2 different objects. the value of this method is needed in several other calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a good idea; in a new class, which references both former classes:

```
public class Three {
    public One One { get; set; }
    public Two Two { get; set; }

    public class Three(One one, Two two) {
        this.One = one;
        this.Two = two;
    }

    public double MethodClassForOne() {
        return (One.item1 * One.item2);
    }

    public double MethodClassForTwo() {
        return (Two.item1 * Two.item2);
    }

    public double MethodClassOneAndTwo()
    {
        return (MethodClassForOne() * MethodClassForTwo());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Just returned because of a notification, and I noticed in your `C` class you have `item3 { get; private set; }`, but it can't be set from the constructor... How will `item3` ever be set?

Comment: I thought about doing this but i don't know if this is a good practice to combine 2 classes in a thirt just to get 1 method back

Comment: @FrederikDeClercq If I can be 100% honest, I don't think any of the code you've written is good practice. The class names are shambles, the dividing up of methods into multiple classes as you have is totally odd, and why you don't want this method to be part of one of those other classes is beyond me. This is the best solution I can think of without being provided information about what you're really trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: @FrederikDeClercq Don't be afraid of having a small class that doesn't do very much. It is true that combining multiple pieces of related functionality into a single class can be good. However, that doesn't mean that separating multiple pieces of functionality into multiple classes is bad.

Answer (score 0):

It really all depends on your design, which is currently a bit vague, but I'd say if you need it in class `C`, then put the method in class `C`.

Again, pay careful attention to the design details.  A class should only have one reason to change (i.e. the "Single Responsibility Principal").  So if that's not really what class `C` is for, then put it in a "class `C` helper class" of some sort.

Comment: I need it in several classes so i cant put it in class C

Comment: I really can't answer your question beyond that without more concrete details.  Calling the classes `One`, `Two`, and `C` and not providing more info about what your design actually does is too vague for a good answer.